# WebAudio Audio Context Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a web application that receives and plays live audio using an `AudioContext` and `decodeAudioData`. Once I get a valid `AudioBuffer`, I then create an `AudioBufferSourceNode`. I then schedule the node to play some time in the future.

The code for that is

```
let sourceNode = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
sourceNode.connect(this.analyserNode);
sourceNode.start(playTime);
```

I also attach events to each `sourceNode`

```
sourceNode.addEventListener('ended', () => {
   sourceNode.disconnect(this.analyserNode);
});
```

It seems that after several hours of this, maybe 16, Chrome will run out of memory. I can definitely watch the RAM of my PC increase in usage but I'm not sure what the exact culprit is. Typical audio data size is 30kb per second, but I am definitely not seeing that kind of memory usage. So I have a feeling that because I never destroy my `AudioContext` until the page is closed, that maybe it continues to hold references to the `AudioBufferSourceNodes` it played hours ago, even though they have `ended` and been disconnected. Maybe there is another disconnect or delete I need to run? Or is this a known problem and I need to periodically create a new `AudioContext`?

---

I cannot reproduce this on FireFox. Appears to be a known memory leak on Chrome...

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554025

Comment: You don't even have to disconnect the node yourself, if it's not referenced anymore and doesn't have new data going through it should get disconnected and GCed automatically. The memory issue probably comes from what you do with the ArrayBuffer and AudioBuffer rather than with the BufferSource node. Could you provide a live [mcve] please? (wikimedia offers some CORS compliant oga files if you need).

Comment: I could, but I edited my post to show the problem with a link to a chrome bug report. They have not fixed it in 5 years so probably never will. If you use decodeAudioData in Chrome, you leak memory. FireFox doesn't.